# How to reference a cell using an input box?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a message box to insert a user-selected cell range.
I want that cell to be the new active cell.
What is the VBA code to do that?

This is the VBA I have, but it doesn't change the active cell.

```
Sub AddClient()

    'Message Box
    Dim userResponce As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    Set userResponce = Application.InputBox("Place curser on Client Name that you want to insert new one above")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If userResponce Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cancel clicked"
    Else
        MsgBox "You selected " & userResponce.Address
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `userResponce.Select`

Comment: Also, specify the `Type` - `Type:=8` - for [`Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox).

Comment: @ScottCraner's solution is the answer - but you may want a `userResponce.Parent.Activate` before `Select`ing, in case that sheet is not active yet.

Comment: Although normally you don't need to `Select`. You can `Insert` a row without `Select`ing.

Comment: Thank you - But I guess I didn't know where to insert your solutions. I tried various ways, but got errors each time. Siddharth detailed solution below worked perfect.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make the cell active then you can use `Application.Goto`. And if you just want to insert the row then you do not need to make the cell active as @BigBen mentioned. You can directly insert the row without activating the cell or the row.

For example

```
userResponce.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Also use `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=8` as shown in [Application.InputBox method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox)

If you want to activate the cell then use the below.

```
Sub AddClient()
    Dim userResponce As Range
    Dim prmt As String

    prmt = "Place cursor on Client Name that you want to insert new one above"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set userResponce = Application.InputBox(prompt:=prmt, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If userResponce Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cancel clicked"
    Else
        Application.Goto Reference:=userResponce
    End If
End Sub
```